# Scala Programming - First Steps in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to Scala and follow the tutorial given in the comprehensive book for Scala Programming by Odersky, Spoon and Venners (see PDF [here](http://ccfit.nsu.ru/~den/Scala/programming_in_scala_2nd.pdf)). I run these examples as recommended in the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate but have troubles with the following codes:

In **Step 4 on p. 74-75** is the description of the exercise (see image below): I think I did what they explain (see images attached) but the .sc file seems not to recognize the "hello.scala" file. Where is the problem?

Thank you.

*Book Description:*

[image: Book]

*My implementation 1:*
[image: My implementation in IntelliJ]

*My implementation 2:*
[image: My implementation in IntelliJ]

Comment: The text `$ scala hello.scala` is a command-line invocation and not something that the IntelliJ IDE will understand. The `$` is the shell's prompt. `scala` is the program being invoked. `hello.scala` is the file being sent to the program so that it can be interpreted and executed.

Comment: So, what do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: If you're trying to follow instructions for running Scala from the command-line then it might be a good idea to put the IDE aside for a while. When you have a fair understanding of Scala files, both scripts and compilable programs, you'll have a better understanding of what the IDE does. If the Scala program is only available from the IDE, and not available to the shell, then the instructions from that book will be a bit confusing.

Comment: please, don't post images, post the code correctly formatted

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute the commands from the terminal. you should
open terminal and `cd` into the directory where the `hello.scala` file is stored.
then run  `scala hello.scala` (please ensure you have scala installed on your machine). 
you will see the output mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it worked. The following helped me:

(1) First installing "brew" via Terminal as explained here: https://brew.sh/

(2) The following site helped me to not only install Scala and SBT but also to install the newest version of Java via Terminal: http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Scala/README.html

(3) Finally, having created the "hello.scala" file (being in folder "/Users/ ... path ... /src/main/scala"), open terminal and enter:

```
ABC:~ XXX$ cd /Users/ ... path ... /src/main/scala 
ABC:scala XXX$ scala hello.scala
Hello, world, from a script!
```